# How to turn this activity into a fragment?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on a sql listview , however I want to display the listview which is in an activity class (CountryListActivity.java) as a fragment in a tablayout . dbManager=newDBManager(this) gives an error when I change it to getActivity , how do I fix this?

```
package com.trinitytabnavigationdrawer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CountryListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DBManager dbManager;

    private ListView listView;

    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    final String[] from = new String[] {
        DatabaseHelper._ID,
            DatabaseHelper.SUBJECT, DatabaseHelper.DESC
    };

    final int[] to = new int[] {
        R.id.id, R.id.title, R.id.desc
    };

    @
    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_emp_list);

        dbManager = new DBManager(this);
        dbManager.open();
        Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_view_record, cursor, from, to, 0);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // OnCLickListiner For List Items
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {@
            Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long viewId) {
                TextView idTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
                TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                TextView descTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

                String id = idTextView.getText().toString();
                String title = titleTextView.getText().toString();
                String desc = descTextView.getText().toString();

                Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ModifyCountryActivity.class);
                modify_intent.putExtra("title", title);
                modify_intent.putExtra("desc", desc);
                modify_intent.putExtra("id", id);

                startActivity(modify_intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @
    Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @
    Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.add_record) {

            Intent add_mem = new Intent(this, AddCountryActivity.class);
            startActivity(add_mem);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

And the database manager class is as follows :

```
package com.trinitytabnavigationdrawer;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DBManager {

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    private Context context;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DBManager(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public DBManager open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insert(String name, String desc) {
        ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
        contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.SUBJECT, name);
        contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.DESC, desc);
        database.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValue);
    }

    public Cursor fetch() {
        String[] columns = new String[] {
            DatabaseHelper._ID, DatabaseHelper.SUBJECT, DatabaseHelper.DESC
        };
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public int update(long _id, String name, String desc) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.SUBJECT, name);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.DESC, desc);
        int i = database.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, DatabaseHelper._ID + " = " + _id, null);
        return i;
    }

    public void delete(long _id) {
        database.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseHelper._ID + "=" + _id, null);
    }
}
```

Please I have no clue what else to do ! Been trying for a week now , sorry I'm not good at this , just following some tutorials ! :(

Comment: If your error is in the Fragment code, show the Fragment and how you loaded it into the Activity, please. Plus, add the logcat for the error

Comment: there is no error except when I am converting the activity into fragment for instance using v.findViewById , I get an unreachable statement when I use getActivity() to replace "this" in  dbManager = new DBManager(this);

Comment: are you trying to convert an activity into fragment? I would recommend rather put your 'reusable' code into a fragment. Call that fragment inside both the activities.

Comment: You need to post the code that's giving you errors, and the details of those errors. We aren't going to guess what you might have done wrong in code we can't see. That's just silly.

Comment: Unreachable statements mean you have a return statement before the marked line. You need to replace `return inflater.inflate...` with `View v = inflater.inflate...` and **then** you have full access to create your database handler before you finally `return v;`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the dbManager and other objects which require context inside `onAttach (Context context)` rather than `onCreateView()` method of Fragment.